# Enviar multiplos arquivos via PHP

Tags: php, html

Olá! Montei um formulário em PHP, está enviando para meu email tudo certinho... A questão é que eu não consigo configurar o input para multiplos arquivos, apenas o envio de 1 arquivo. Algém pode me mostrar uma luz? Segue a forma que esta no arquivo HTML e PHP:

```
<input id="arquivo" name="arquivo" class="input-file" type="file">
```

---

```
/* Função que codifica o anexo para poder ser enviado na mensagem  */
if(file_exists($arquivo["tmp_name"]) and !empty($arquivo)){

    $fp = fopen($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"],"rb"); // Abri o arquivo enviado.
    $anexo = fread($fp,filesize($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"])); // Le o arquivo aberto na linha anterior
    $anexo = base64_encode($anexo); // Codifica os dados com MIME para o e-mail 
    fclose($fp); // Fecha o arquivo aberto anteriormente
    $anexo = chunk_split($anexo); // Divide a variável do arquivo em pequenos pedaços para poder enviar
    $mensagem = "--$boundary\n"; // Nas linhas abaixo possuem os parâmetros de formatação e codificação, juntamente com a inclusão do arquivo anexado no corpo da mensagem
    $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n\n";
    $mensagem.= "$corpo_mensagem\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "--$boundary\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."\n";  
    $mensagem.= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo["name"]."\"\n";  
    $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";  
    $mensagem.= "$anexo\n";  
    $mensagem.= "--$boundary--\r\n"; 
}
    else // Caso não tenha anexo
    {
        $mensagem = "--$boundary\n"; 
        $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
        $mensagem.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n\n";
        $mensagem.= "$corpo_mensagem\n";
}



/* Função que envia a mensagem  */
if(mail($to, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers))
{
    header("Location: /briefing/registration_send.php");
} 
    else
    {
        echo "<br><br><center><b><font color='red'>Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apenas um `input` creio que não seja possível, mas você pode criar vários inputs, atribuindo o `name`como um `array` e depois você faz um `for` por dentro dele e sobe um arquivo por vez, segue exemplo.

```
<input name="arquivo[]" class="input-file" type="file">
<input name="arquivo[]" class="input-file" type="file">
<input name="arquivo[]" class="input-file" type="file">
```

O `id` por ser único você não coloca ou faz um `loop` em `php` para colocar um contador no final do mesmo e pega por `$_FILES` utilizando o `name` ou `id` se for o caso, como ele vai como array você faz um `for` assim.

```
/*Aqui você verifica se o file está setado */
if (isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
  foreach ($_FILES['arquivo']["name"] as $file => $key) {
    /*Aqui você evita de tentar enviar inputs vazios */
    if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']["name"][$file])) {
      /*RESTANTE DO SEU CÓDIGO AQUI*/
    }
  }
}
```

Se vpcê precisa de algo mais dinâmico pode adicionar um botão de `mais arquivos` e por `JavaScript` ou `Jquery` você adiciona um novo campo com a mesmas propriedades. ;)

Comment: Pts então... Neste caso o problema é que precisaria aparecer apenas um input para adicionar vários arquivos :/

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link, ele tem dicas sobre como fazer isso em `html5`, com um input único na mesma idéia de `input` como `array` e o atributo `multiple` no `input` https://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/html5_upload_de_varios_arquivos_com_apenas_um_input.php

Comment: Cara eu tentei fazer isto, copiei este código... mas ao enviar, da erro de página...

Comment: Me fala melhor que erro ele apresenta, se possível hospeda um print com as imagens pra vermos o que está acontecendo assim como o código que fez.